# Cataloging item during creation vs. updating cataloging information

Tags: forms, interaction-design

Lets say it is possible to add an item with come hierarchical cataloging information.
For my use case example the item is a fault report.
The end user is a mechanic who is not an expert with computers.

After some surveys and field research I came to the conclusion that the easiest way for the current end-user to catalog a fault report is with a wizard like design that look something like this.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHUXhK.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This is a simplified version of the add fault form (wizard).

Now the question is how would one update an existing fault ?
The categories are a hierarchy and i really want to avoid complex control (for mechanics) such as Dropdown menues with a tree view inside or even just a tree view to re-catalog the fault report.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Does/will the system recognise individual mechanics? or is it a dumb-terminal with one user?

Comment: to allow user to update, he should be provided with existing faults, right ? For this you should depend on the data grid kind of component. Even though the user is not an expert with computers, you need to make use of simplest possible UI components and user training should bring in ease of use

Comment: True there will be a grid .. or a list .. but how would the update from look like and how should i allow them to re-catalog the fault.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful. Have a data grid shown on selecting category. **Edit button** in each row leads to **edit dialog**. **Add button** below the grid leads to **Add dialog**

[image]

Comment: Great! now the question is.. in the EDIT dialog ... how would you change a category ? i.e. re-Catalog. sorry but this is not an answer but I will use your extended mockup to update my question so it will be more cleare.

Comment: This can be done in many ways. 1. In Edit dialog, on Commit, take the user directly to Category selection screen. User can select the list of faults of a category again. 2. Do not show category selection at all. Show the faults list sorted on category. After the commit in Edit Dialog, show the faults list again after refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to edit the category as if you were actually choosing a new category for a new report.

Since the users are not expert, they probably won't mind having to choose the category from the start, without being able to choose only from the second or third level down. Even better, they will probably find it even easier than to actually edit the existing report.